# Simplify equations for a computer algebric system in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, symbolic-math

IHello! I'm currently trying to code in ocaml a programm to draw a function which was write by the user.

To do that, I'm parsing the input, I'm tranforming the input into a data structure.
I'm currently trying to create an ocaml function to simplify at maximum this input.

For example, x*x - x*x will simplify in 0

Here is my parser :

```
%{
    open Function
%}

%token <float> FLOAT
%token <string> VAR
%token COS SIN SQRT EXP LN PUIS
%token PLUS MINUS TIMES DIV
%token LPAR RPAR
%token EOL
%left LPAR RPAR
%left COS SIN SQRT EXP LN
%left PLUS MINUS
%left TIMES DIV
%left PUIS
%type <Function.formel> main
%start main
%%

main:
expr EOL                    { $1 }
;

expr:
|   FLOAT                       { flt $1 }
|   VAR                         { var $1 }
|   FLOAT VAR                   { mul (flt $1) (var $2) }
|   LPAR expr RPAR              { $2 }
|   expr TIMES expr             { mul $1 $3 }
|   expr DIV expr               { div $1 $3 }
|   expr PLUS expr              { add $1 $3 }
|   expr MINUS expr             { sub $1 $3 }
|   expr PUIS expr              { puis $1 $3 }
|   COS LPAR expr RPAR          { cos $3 }
|   PLUS expr                   { pos $2 }
|   MINUS expr                  { neg $2 }
|   FLOAT COS LPAR expr RPAR    { mul (flt $1) (cos $4) }
|   SIN LPAR expr RPAR          { sin $3 }
|   FLOAT SIN LPAR expr RPAR    { mul (flt $1) (sin $4) }
|   SQRT LPAR expr RPAR         { sqrt $3 }
|   LN LPAR expr RPAR           { lnp $3 }
|   EXP LPAR expr RPAR          { expo $3 }
;
```

Here is my lexer :

```
{
    open Parser
    exception Eof
}

rule token = parse
  | [' ' '\t']          { token lexbuf }
  | ['\n']              { EOL }
  | ['0'-'9']+ as lxm   { FLOAT (float_of_string lxm) }
  | '+'                 { PLUS }
  | '-'                 { MINUS }
  | '*'                 { TIMES }
  | '/'                 { DIV }
  | '('                 { LPAR }
  | ')'                 { RPAR }
  | '^'                 { PUIS }
  | "cos"               { COS }
  | "sin"               { SIN }
  | "sqrt"              { SQRT }
  | "ln"                { LN }
  | "exp"               { EXP }
  | ['a'-'z']+ as lxm   { VAR (lxm) }
  | eof                 { raise Eof }
```

I think my parser and my lexer are good.

Then, I'm using a tree to store the function :

```
type formel =
| Float of float
| Var of string
| Add of formel * formel
| Sub of formel * formel
| Mul of formel * formel
| Div of formel * formel
| Ln of formel
| Cos of formel
| Sin of formel
| Puis of formel * formel
| Sqrt of formel
| Exp of formel

let flt f = Float f
let add e1 e2 = Add (e1, e2)
let sub e1 e2 = Sub (e1, e2)
let mul e1 e2 = Mul (e1, e2)
let div e1 e2 = Div (e1, e2)
let puis e1 e2 = Puis (e1, e2)
let neg e = Mul (Float (-1.), e)
let pos e = Mul (Float 1., e)
let cos e = Cos e
let sin e = Sin e
let var v = Var v
let sqrt e = Sqrt e
let expo e = Exp e
let lnp e = Ln e
```

And here is the difficulty where I am : the creation of a function to simplify.

```
        let rec simplify f =
        let f_simplify = simp f in
        if f_simplify = f 
        then f_simplify 
        else simplify f_simplify
        and simp f = 
        match f with
        | Float f -> Float f
        | Var x -> Var x

        (* 0 + x -> x *)
        | Add (Float 0., f) -> simp f
        (* x + 0 -> x *)
        | Add (f, Float 0.) -> simp f
        (* f1 + f2-> calcul (f1 + f2) *)
        | Add (Float f1, Float f2) -> Float (f1 +. f2)
        (* x + x -> 2 * x *)
        | Add (f, g) when f = g -> simp (Mul (Float 2., simp f))

        (* f1 * x + x -> (f1 + 1) * x *)
        | Add (Mul (Float f1, f), g) when f = g -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 +. 1.), simp f))
        (* x + f1 * x -> (f1 + 1) * x *)
        | Add (f, Mul (Float f1, g)) when f = g -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 +. 1.), simp f))
        (* x * f1 + x -> (f1 + 1) * x *)
        | Add (Mul (f, Float f1), g) when f = g -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 +. 1.), simp f))
        (* x + x * f1 -> (f1 + 1) * x *)
        | Add (f, Mul (g, Float f1)) when f = g -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 +. 1.), simp f))

        (* f1 * x + f2 * x -> (f1 + f2) * x *)
        | Add (Mul (Float f1, f), Mul (Float f2, g)) when f = g -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 +. f2), simp f))
        (* x * f1 + f2 * x -> (f1 + f2) * x *)
        | Add (Mul (f, Float f1), Mul (Float f2, g)) when f = g -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 +. f2), simp f))
        (* f1 * x + x * f2 -> (f1 + f2) * x *)
        | Add (Mul (Float f1, f), Mul (g, Float f2)) when f = g -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 +. f2), simp f))
        (* x * f1 + x * f2 -> (f1 + f2) * x *)
        | Add (Mul (f, Float f1), Mul (g, Float f2)) when f = g -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 +. f2), simp f))

        | Add (f, g) -> Add (simp f, simp g)

        (* 0 - x -> - x *)
        | Sub (Float 0., f) -> simp (Mul (Float (-1.), simp f))
        (* x - 0 -> x *)
        | Sub (f, Float 0.) -> simp f
        (* f1 - f2 -> calcul (f1 - f2) *)
        | Sub (Float f1, Float f2) -> Float (f1 -. f2)
        (* f1 * x + x -> (f1 + 1) * x *)
        | Sub (f, g) when f = g -> Float 0.

        | Sub (f, g) -> Sub (simp f, simp g)

        (* 0 / x -> 0 *)
        | Div (Float 0., f) -> Float 0.
        (* x / 1 -> x *)
        | Div (f, Float 1.) -> simp f
        (* f1 / f2 -> calcul (f1 / f2) *)
        | Div (Float f1, Float f2) -> Float (f1 /. f2)
        (* x / x -> 1 *)
        | Div (f, g) when f = g -> Float 1.

        | Div (f, g) -> Div (simp f, simp g)

        (* 1 * x -> x *)
        | Mul (Float 1., f) -> simp f
        (* x * 1 -> x *)
        | Mul (f, Float 1.) -> simp f
        (* 0 * x -> 0 *)
        | Mul (Float 0., f) -> Float 0.
        (* x * 0 -> 0 *)
        | Mul (f, Float 0.) -> Float 0.
        (* f1 * f2 -> calcul (f1 * f2) *)
        | Mul (Float f1, Float f2) -> Float (f1 *. f2)

        (* x * x -> x ^ 2 *)
        | Mul (f, g) when f = g -> simp (Puis (simp f, Float 2.))
        (* x ^ a * x -> x ^ (a + 1) *)
        | Mul (Puis (f, g), h) when f = h -> Puis (simp f, simp (Add (simp g, Float 1.)))

        (* (f1 * x) * f2 -> (f1 * f2) * x *)
        | Mul (Mul (Float f1, f), Float f2) -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 *. f2), simp f))
        (* f1 * (f2 * x) -> (f1 * f2) * x *)
        | Mul (Float f1, Mul (Float f2, f)) -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 *. f2), simp f))
        (* (x * f1) * f2 -> (f1 * f2) * x *)
        | Mul (Mul (f, Float f1), Float f2) -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 *. f2), simp f))
        (* f1 * (x * f2) -> (f1 * f2) * x *)
        | Mul (Float f1, Mul (f, Float f2)) -> simp (Mul (Float (f1 *. f2), simp f))

        | Mul (f, g) -> Mul (simp f, simp g)

        (* x ^ 0 -> 1 *)
        | Puis (f, Float 0.) -> Float 1.
        (* 0 ^ x -> 0 *)
        | Puis (Float 0., f) -> Float 0.
        (* x ^ 1 -> x *)
        | Puis (f, Float 1.) -> simp f

        | Puis (f, g) -> Puis (simp f, simp g)

        | Ln f -> Ln (simp f)
        | Cos f -> Cos (simp f)
        | Sin f -> Sin (simp f)
        | Sqrt f -> Sqrt (simp f)
        | Exp f -> Exp (simp f)
```

Here is my problem :
For simple function as x*x + x*x, this function works.
But if I enter the function : 2 + x*x - x*x, there is no simplification done. The result is : 2 + x^2 - x^2

I have no idea how I can fix this problem, I'm on it since 3 days.

I hope everything is clear, and someone can give me some tips !
Have a great day !

Comment: If your tree looks like `(2 + x*x) - x*x` there would seem to be no locus to apply the simplification. What if you enter `2 + (x*x - x*x)`?

Comment: If I enter 2 + (x\*x - x\*x), the result is good : it's 2 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in two folds:

1. If you draw out the tree, you will see that subtree is not equal.
2. You do it in the top-down manner. Normally, a simplification should be done bottom up( from higher to lower precedence e.g. `2+x*x+x*x ==> 2+x^2+x^2 ==> 2+2x^2` )

Your equation is of this tree:

`- : formel =
   Sub (Add (Float 2., Mul (Var "x", Var "x")), Mul (Var "x", Var "x"))`

Let's follows the execution sequences:

1. it matches `Sub (f, g) -> Sub (simp f, simp g)`
   with

   `f = Add (Float 2., Mul (Var "x", Var "x"))`

   `g = Mul (Var "x", Var "x")`
2. from (1) it executes `simp f`, hence matches `Add (f, g) -> Add (simp f, simp g)`

   2.1. it matches `Float(2.)` with `Float f -> Float f`

   2.2. it matches `Mul(Var("x"),Var("x"))` with `Mul (f, g) when f = g -> simp (Puis (simp f, Float 2.))`
3. it continues on `simp g`, hence matches `Mul (f, g) when f = g -> simp (Puis (simp f, Float 2.))`

That's why you got the result of:

`Sub (Add (Float 2., Puis (Var "x", Float 2.)), Puis (Var "x", Float 2.))`

(2 + x^2 - x^2)

because the left(`2 + x^2`) and right(`x^2`) subtrees aren't equal.

---

To solve problem (1)

One idea is to add commutative property of addition rules and transform it to a list of same precedences. For example,

`Sub(f,Add(g,h)) -> [Plus(f),Minus(g),Minus(h)]`

with this you can identify the same subtrees and eliminate them.

To solve problem (2)
You need to simplify based on the precedence of operators, e.g. `x*x` becomes `x^2` before `x+x` is simplified to `2x`. This can be done by altering to code to run parsing multiple times. Each time that subtree has changed, rerun the simplification on the upper tree.

---

Another idea is to archive it through Unification & substitution technique. I haven't thought it through. But it quite convincing that's doable.

Comment: Thanks you very much for that help ! I will think on it !

But I don't understand what you propose at the end of your message... Can you rephrase it please ? Or maybe give a short example ?

Comment: @Mathemataume take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science) .

Comment: @Mathemataume if the answer helps you, please accept it or vote up.

Comment: I think I solve the problem (1). But some questions remains :
- How can I do simplification with bottom-top manner ? Should I do something like visit each node of my tree with a specific manner ? Or something else ?
- For simplify an equation like x^x/x into x, should I create the same type of function as I create to solve problem (1) ? For example, x^2/x will be represents by [Times (2, Var x), Division (1, Var x] -> [Times (1, Var x)]

Comment: You can do it in multi-passes. Keep running the simplifier until subtree doesn't change anymore. Or the other option is using a technique like Continuation-passing though that is quite challenging if you are not familiar with FP.